# Defective Built-in Hotspot Feature

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, hot-spot

After a fresh install of 14.04, I tried the built-in **create a Hotspot** feature on `System Settings>Network`. Turns out, my wireless card does not support this feature on Linux (though I can create wireless hotpost on Windows 7, but this belongs to another question). Anyway, whenever I open my `System Settings>Network`, I see that hotspot is on, even though I closed it before. If I enable Aeroplane mode on, still hotspot mode stays on. The main problem is, since hotspot is on, it prohibits me to connect to any wireless network. Any suggestion will be most appreciated.

my wifi card:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:44:f0:91:e5  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:6
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 00:16:44:f0:91:e5
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8187 driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `sudo ap-hotspot stop`. This will stop hotspot. Also you can disable service to start on boot with `sudo update-rc.d hostapd disable`

Comment: I get this error: `sudo: ap-hotspot: command not found`

Comment: Try `sudo /etc/init.d/hostapd stop`

Comment: Didn't do anything. When I check Networks, I can still see Hotspot is on.

Comment: Ok, maybe is for you solution best to remove hostapd packet `sudo apt-get remove hostapd`. After removing restart networking servis or you can restart pc.